# How to edit Table and Figure text to bold font

Tags: r, fonts, bookdown, kableextra

I'm creating a PDF bookdown file. However, I'm unable to edit the Table and Figure headers, such that the text "Figure X" and "Table X" are in bold. For example,

**Table 1** my first table

**Figure 2** my second figure

Here is the code that I ran, modified with the starwars dataset:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
date: "2023-03-22"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
toc: FALSE
---

```{r tab2, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
sw <- starwars[, c("name", "height", "mass", "films")]
kable(sw, "latex", booktabs = TRUE, longtable = TRUE, linesep = "", caption = "Some chars", align = "l") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position", "repeat_header"), position="left") %>% 
  column_spec(4, width = "8cm") %>% 
  row_spec(0,bold=TRUE)
```
````

Are you able to advise?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `labelfont=bf` option in the `{caption}`
package:

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false, labelfont=bf]{caption}
---

```{r tab2, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
sw <- starwars[, c("name", "height", "mass", "films")]
kable(sw, "latex", booktabs = TRUE, longtable = TRUE, linesep = "", caption = "Some chars", align = "l") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position", "repeat_header"), position="left") %>% 
  column_spec(4, width = "8cm") %>% 
  row_spec(0,bold=TRUE)
```
````

**Output**:

[image]